# Flask-login doesn't call load_user, authentication doesn't persist

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Logging in by sending post requests to '/api/login' never returns "User is already logged in", and going to 'api/user' never returns the email of the authenticated user. I tried placing a print statement in the `load_user` function and it was never called, but the user successfully generates an id, that can be printed after it is created and committed into the database. Registration, db persistence, login all work correctly, the user just doesn't stay authenticated in between requests.

```
init.py
# standard library imports

# third-party imports
from flask import Flask 

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_login import LoginManager

# lcoal
from site_t.config import Config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.session_protection = "strong"


@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()


from site_t import routes, models
```

```
models.py

from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

from site_t import db, login

@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin): 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.email)

    def set_password(self, password): 
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password) 

    def check_password(self, password): 
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
```

```
Routes.py 

# third party imports
from flask import request, jsonify
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, login_required


# local imports
from site_t import app, db 
from site_t.models import User
from site_t.communication.receiver import parse_login_request, parse_registration_request


# NOTE: This route is needed for the default EB health check route
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Welcome to the API'})

@app.route("/api/login", methods=["POST"])   # type: ignore
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return jsonify({"message": "User already logged in"}), 200

    try:
        email, password = parse_login_request(request)
    except ValueError as e:
        return jsonify({"message": str(e)}), 400

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    

    if user is None or not user.check_password(password):
        return jsonify({"message": "Invalid email or password"}), 200

    login_user(user, remember=True)

    return jsonify({"message": "Login successful"}), 200



def create_user(email, password):
    user = User(email=email)
    user.set_password(password)
    return user

@app.route("/api/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])   # type: ignore
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return jsonify({"message": "User already logged in"}), 400

    try: 
        email, password = parse_registration_request(request)
    except ValueError as e:
        return jsonify({"message": str(e)}), 400
    
    if User.query.filter_by(email=email).first() is not None:
        return jsonify({"message": "Email already registered"}), 200

    user = create_user(email, password) 


    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({"message": "Registration successful"}), 200


@app.route("/api/user", methods=["GET, POST"])   # type: ignore
@login_required
def get_user():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return jsonify({"message": "User not logged in"}), 400

    return jsonify({"email": current_user.email})
```

```
wsgi.py
from site_t import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: It would be also useful to know what `login()` and `get_user()` do return, beside what they don't.

Comment: @JonathanCiapetti login() returns "Login successful" and get_user returns "User not logged in" when the correct login details are provied

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).